# Lost volumne down + power button function to take a screenshot

Tags: mapping, keyboard-shortcuts, screenshot, gesture

My moto gesture app has removed the lost volumne down + power button function to take a screenshot. I have searched the settings menu for half an hour, read online for half an hour, installed 3th party apps, for for the world of me, I can't find where te remap those buttons to this function or to restore it to the defaults, like it was  working before.

Any suggestions? Android menu looks different on a edge 40, sadly.